# Date.parse ddd mmm dd hh:mm:ss UTC +nnnn issues in FX15 OSX

Tags: javascript, date

I was expecting to be able to parse this format
`var dStr = "Thu Aug 2 12:20:12 UTC +0100";`
but no go in Fx15. Chrome seems quite happy

What is the above called (RFC...) and would it be worth my while to try to get date.js to handle it - seems it has not been updated since 2008 http://code.google.com/p/datejs/

UPDATE: I now notice the missing YYYY - adding it fixes the issue
The OP forgot to give me the yyyy - the format is 
"Thu Aug 2 12:20:12 UTC +0100 2012"

UPDATE: ALSO Works with date.js if I do

`Date.parse(dStr.replace(" UTC",""))`;

**Tryouts:**

- native: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/KWTb2/ - no go in FX15 osx
- moment.js: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/J9gH9/ - works if I add year
- date.js with replace: http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/SQrgW/ (works)
- Adding year works (FX15, OSX) http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dYNLD/

I'll try to get the OP to add a year server side

Comment: Remove the `date.js` in your last jsfiddle example, you will find both works well.http://jsfiddle.net/TbDXD/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string is valid format.

```
console.log(new Date("Thu Aug 2 12:20:12 UTC +0100"));
```

***Edit:*** 
In firefox, it seems you need to specify the year.
[The DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KWTb2/2/).

Comment: @mplungjan That is because you missed the `year` in the date string. It seems you need to specify the year in firefox.

Comment: I did not miss anything. The date string is in the format it is.

Comment: Fx still does not like `Thu Aug 2 2012 12:20:12 UTC +0100`

Comment: Sillyness. http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dYNLD/ new Date works, Date.parse does not!

Comment: Yeah, forked the wrong fiddle - not a complete answer, but I need to get the OP to add the year to get a valid date string

Answer (score 1):

Try http://momentjs.com/. It's up to date with recent releases at the very least.

Comment: getting invalid date here: var dStr="Thu Aug 2 12:20:12 UTC +0100";
alert(moment(dStr)) - http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/J9gH9/

Comment: it works in chrome but not FF.  Why is the year missing from the string?

Comment: I am asking that too... Will get back